# Add the elements in a row, for each row, in a matrix, using theano

Tags: python, theano

I have a vector v and a matrix z, say

```
v = theano.shared(rng.normal(0, 1, 10))
z = theano.shared(rng.normal(0, 1, (10, 10)))
```

I want to create a new vector y given by v + sum of elements in each row of z.
Basically: y[i] = v[i] + T.sum(z[:,i]) that I can do, for each entry, by:

```
y[i] = v[i] + theano.tensor.sum(z[:][i])
```

My question is: is there a way, without doing a loop, to write y = v + T.sum(rows of z) in one single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain it like this

```
y = v + z.sum(axis=1)
```

In numpy, and thus in theano, many aggregator functions, such as `sum`, `mean`, `var`, `std`, `any`, `all`, ... have an `axis` keyword argument, and sometimes even an `axes` keyword argument, with which you can specify exactly in which direction you array is to be traversed.

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thank you!